# Why does QtCreator 3.0.0 on Linux omit some instructions in its disassembly view?

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb, qt-creator

When I use the disassemble command in gdb I get a disassembly of every instruction in the current function, like this:

```
40057c:  mov    edi,0x400747
400581:  mov    eax,0x0
400586:  call   0x400440 <printf@plt>
40058b:  mov    esi,0x10
400590:  mov    edi,0x40075d
400595:  mov    eax,0x0
40059a:  call   0x400440 <printf@plt>
40059f:  movabs rax,0x400921fb54442d18
4005a9:  mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
4005ad:  call   0x400544 <InlineDebugTest()>
4005b2:  movsd  xmm0,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
```

When I look at disassembly in QtCreator 3.0 (either from selecting Debug->Operate by Instruction or by right-clicking on EIP in the registers window and selecting Open Disassembler at ) I find that the 'call' instructions are all omitted, as shown below:

```
40057c:  mov    edi,0x400747
400581:  mov    eax,0x0
     12 printf("kFooBar == %u\n", kFooBar);
40058b:  mov    esi,0x10
400590:  mov    edi,0x40075d
400595:  mov    eax,0x0
     14 double pi = 3.14159265358979323;
40059f:  movabs rax,0x400921fb54442d18
4005a9:  mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
     16 InlineDebugTest();
4005b2:  movsd  xmm0,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
```

I also find that in long functions QtCreator often fails to show the beginning of the function -- hundreds of bytes of disassembly are omitted. Is this a known problem? Is the omitting of the 'call' instructions intentional?

Comment: This has been fixed. The bug was that QtCreator was incorrectly parsing the disassembly results from gdb when the "set print max-symbolic-offset 1" command was used. I had that in my .gdbinit. I reported this in February 2014 and it was fixed the next day.

https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-11504